# How would I go about finding a specific sequence of letters within a dataset that has a list of letters?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so sorry if this is a simple question. I basically have a dataset that has a list of letters. How would I go about finding if a specific sequence of letters such as "agtggt" exists, and if it does, how many of them exist?

I tried to do something with the ifelse function:

```
ifelse("a" %in% chain,"yes","no" )
```

My approach was to basically tell R to find "a" and that if it does, find "g", and that if it does, find "t", etc. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try `grepl`

```
c("no","yes")[1+grepl("agtggt",chain)]
```

If you want to know how many `"agtggt"` exists in `chain`, you can try

```
length(regmatches(chain,gregexpr("agtggt",chain))[[1]])
```

Comment: See the issue is the dataset that I have is a string of characters (there are 5000 characters). I did try to use the function you mentioned, but it does not recognize that the datatset chain has a string of characters, so even if you type "ag", of which there are a lot in the dataset called chain, it still says "no." This is why I was trying to use the ifelse function as well as %in%.

Comment: [Here is a link with documentation on regular expressions](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/regular-expressions.html). It also has link to explanatory video. 
To add on your current problem, seems like @Jay is having vector of chars so you could try proposed approach by turning vector into string as follows: `chain_string <- paste(chain, collapse = '')`

Comment: @JānisGredzens Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jay @JānisGredzens Yes, exactly. I wasn't aware of that `chain` is a array of single characters, then `pasteo(chain, collapse = '')` should make things work

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer that @ThomasIsCoding provided, you could also create your own function for such searching purpose as follows:

```
# vector sample
chain <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 't', 'c', 'a', 't', 't')
# define function
string_finder <- function(sequence_string, target_variable) {
  # get sequence_string length
  len_seq <- nchar(sequence_string)
  # get reference for last iteration
  iter_end <- length(target_variable) - len_seq + 1
  # set occurances variable
  occurances <- 0
  # loop through vector
  i <- 1
  while (i < iter_end) {
    # if match found -> continue looking only after match
    if (sequence_string == paste0(target_variable[i:(i+len_seq-1)], collapse = '')) {
      occurances = occurances+1
      i = i+len_seq
    } else {
      # else continue with the next position
      i = i+1
    }
  }
  return(occurances)
}
# example
string_finder("agt", chain)
```

This way you would avoid working with regular expressions.